How to create and run a virtual environment for my Python programs in VS Code ? I want a few selected programms to run in a separate environment
I am using VS Code text editor for my Python programming. I need to know how to create virtual environments in VS Code for a project specific file.
I haven't tried anything since I am unaware of the procedure to create a virtual environment in VS Code.

The Python PATH you can setup when you are installing Python, if you checked it. Or you can use sublime text to code and cmd to run. Its better way than trying to setup envi on VS Code with Python
